Build Issue due to $(Platform) default value
We are facing build issue when we try to build .net project in custom project configuration, like Debug configuration we have added LinuxDebug as a configuration in project to target it for corss platform. But when we try to build using that configuration we are getting dependent project dll not found issue as its looking in different directory.
In project file we have mentioned following
$(SolutionDir)\Output\bin$(Platform)$(Configuration)
the refered project is looking that dll in wrong directory, because somehow $(Platform) gets AnyCPU value, but at project level we have mentioned x64.
we are not sure where exactly  AnyCPU value gets assigned to $(Platform)
referred/dependent dll is there in x64 directory.
Can someone please help me here
I checked project properties build section's PlatformTarget where x64 is mentioned, and checked project configuration where also PlatformTarget set to x64, not sure how PlatformTarget gets AnyCPU value

I create a brand new sample project which name is testdemo. According to your requirement, I add below configuration to support linuxdebug.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
     <!-- add this line for linux -->
     <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- add custom configuration -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='LinuxDebug|x64'">
        <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\Output\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);LINUXDEBUG</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Default configuration -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Then I am using dotnet publish -c LinuxDebug -r linux-x64 --self-contained false command to test it. Here is the test result.



Thanks Jason for your input,
But at project file we have already mentioned following , and not sure where its referring AnyCPU, we have searched in overall project but not able to find.

Library
x64
false
built locally
$(SolutionDir)\Output\bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)
Debug;Release;LinuxDebug;LinuxRelease

@Omkar I want to make it clear, are you having trouble compiling with vs2022, or are you running into it using the command line in the answer? Because I need to rule out if it's because of the issue that VS2022 brings. Thanks for your patience.
